# How do I make text stop at a certain point and go onto the next line?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to put an image on the left side, and text on the right side. I've managed to do this, however, the text goes all the way till the end of the page until it breaks off onto a new line, which is not what I want it to do. I'd like it to stop around the same Y position as my navigation bar stops, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've looked around and tried a few different methods, but none of them seemed to work.

**MY HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LoL</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<a href="#Best champions for each role"><img src="assets/lol.png" alt="Logo" 
id="image1"></a>
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#Farming">Farming</a></li>
<li><a href="#Best champions for each role">Best champions for each role</a>
</li>
</ul>
<img src="assets/minions.png" alt="Minions in LoL" id="image2" >
<p1>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
accusantium 
doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore 
veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim  
ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia 
consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque 
porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, 
adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et 
dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis 
nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid 
ex ea commodi 
consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit 
esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo 
voluptas nulla pariatur?</p1>
<banner></banner>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY CSS**

```
#image1 {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 8%;
width: 30%;
}

#image2 {
width: 30%;
right: 200px;
margin-left: 285px;
float: left;
border: 5px;
border-style: groove;
border-color: black;
}

ul {
top: 150px;
display: flex;
list-style-type:none;
width:60%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(163,21,23,1.00)
}

li {
float: right;
width: 33.33%;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
border: thin;
border-style: groove;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

body {
background-color: rgba(96,96,96,1.00)
}

p1 {
font-family: Comic Sans MS;
font-size: 11px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap? If so: do you know about <div>?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by bootstrap (i'm new to web etc). I use Dreamweaver to put in the HTML/CSS and some of it I took off the internet, but edited it so that it fits my website content. I'm practicing for my website design class and was told to not use <div> :P

Comment: Welcome to the web! ;). well basically bootstrap allows you to use an awesome well made css. If you do not use such pre designed as bootstrap you need to create your own css. Best is to add `max-width:100%;`  to your css. I suggest to look at getbootstrap.com, it makes your live easier :P. Perfect example can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbmXOZ

Comment: I would probably use one if I was doing something non-school related, but in the class I have I get 6 hours to create a website, and one of the requirements states that I must write my own CSS, which is why I cannot use a bootstrap for this :/ But i'd probably use one if it was for non-educational purposes. With the max-width:100% , which part of the code should I add this in to ?

Comment: Ok, I get it. Let's take a look at your code. First I need to have explained what you need (the design). I dont understand this yet. (perhaps because i lack in english)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rJfHx This is what my website looks like. Currently the text goes over the red line (I made that red line) and I'd like the text to stop just before the red line, and then carry on onto another line underneath, where the arrow is pointing. That's basically what I want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for the picture. One second. Ill show you

Comment: Alright, a small explanation: As you designed your buttons (ul css): `display:flex`, `width:60%` you also need to style your text. I would have done is else, but a quick and dirty fix should be adding as answer below

Comment: Answer added. Please test it and let me know the results

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but what is p1?

Comment: Paragraph 1 from whay i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you designed all different tags in your `CSS` you should also design the `p1`text properly.

A dirty and quick fix would be something like:

```
p1 {
        font-family: Comic Sans MS;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        display: flex;
        list-style-type:none;
        width:60%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Change your current p1 css to this one. This is NOT clean code, but as you noted it's a school project which need to be done within 6 hours, just do it dirty as above.

Good luck at your school's project.

Comment: Thank you for this. Im currently away from my pc so i cant test it, but i'll do it as soon as im home and let you know if it worked :)

P.s why is this "dirty code" ? :D

Comment: It worked partially. Where the line should end is fine, as it ends near enough where the red line is from that image I sent, however, it moved under the image rather than besides it.

Also, which margin should I use ? :) as You put margin-left: 50px; and margin-left: auto;

Comment: You could style the image. As for the margin-left, just use the one which works :P. im not on my laptop now, and im not a pro at css to tell out of my memory. What could work is adding the image inside the p1 tag, not sure tho. can you tell me if one of these work?

Comment: I've fixed it :) It was a mixture of research and going on IRC channels, but in the end, I put both the image and the text inside a wrapper and gave it an overall width of 60%, which is also the width of my nav bar. I then styled each appropriately and it worked :D

Comment: Nice found! Basically the same as i noted  if you think my answer was your answer to a solution feel free to mark my answer as the answer. Goodluck with your project